# boton para enviar imagen emoji con ayax

Tags: php, mysql, mensajes

Estoy creando un chat, me gustaría enviar emojis con botones preestablecidos.
De momento tengo lo siguiente en el fichero de guardar el mensaje:
Si el imput field lo relleno con un texto específico, me lo sustituye por una imagen.
Pero lo que busco es que al clickar un botón aparte con el icono me recoja la imagen y lo envíe directamente

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
        include_once ("conexion.php");
        $outgoing_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectiondb, $_POST['outgoing_id']);
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectiondb, $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectiondb, $_POST['message']);

        //remplazar mensaje por emoji
        $message = str_replace(':D', "<img src=\'emojis/heart.png\'/>", $message);

        if(!empty($message)){
            $sql = mysqli_query($connectiondb, "INSERT INTO messages (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg)
                                VALUES ({$incoming_id}, {$outgoing_id}, '{$message}')") or die();
        }
    }else{
        header("../main.php");
    }
?>
```

Fichero js sin emojis, solo envío de mensajes normales:
es desde donde necesitaría declarar el botón y envia rel mensaje:

```
sendBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    //ayax
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating XML object
    xhr.open("POST", "../controllers/insert-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            inputField.value = "";
            scrollToBottom();
        }
        }
    }
 
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

parte del código html del input y los botonoes:

```
<form action="#" class="typing-area" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="outgoing_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['unique_id']; ?>" hidden>
                <input type="text" name="incoming_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" hidden>
                <input type="text" name="message" class="input-field" placeholder="Type a message here...">
                <button><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
            </form>
            <!--icon button sender-->
            <div class="icon-area">
                    <button class="icon" class="house"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></button>
                    <button class="icon" class="heart"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button>
                    <button class="icon" class="flower"><i class="fa-duotone fa-flower"></i></button>
                    <button class="icon" class="beer"><i class="fa-solid fa-beer-mug-empty"></i></button>
                    <button class="icon" class="wine"><i class="fa-solid fa-wine-glass"></i></button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Y cual sería ese texto específico?

Comment: Y lo he resuelto al final: con java script obtengo el valor del botón por el id. luego el imput field del chat. Entonces sustituyo el mensaje por la imagen que quiero en el imput.
Gracias!

Answer (score -3):

PUEDES USAR ESTE CODIGO

Esto enviá lo que necesitas a insertar, no es necesario nada mas

aqui un detalle del envio por post
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el mensaje se enviá como html.

```js
// Seleccionamos los elementos HTML con sus respectivos IDs
const miDiv = document.querySelector("#miDiv");
const BotonSend = document.querySelector("#BotonSend");
const DivGeneral = document.querySelector("#DivGeneral");

// Seleccionamos todos los botones con clase "icon"
const botones = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");

// Iteramos sobre cada botón y le agregamos un evento click
botones.forEach(boton => {
  boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Obtenemos el id del botón que fue clickeado
    const id = this.id;

    // Verificamos el id y agregamos el texto correspondiente
    switch (id) {
      case "house":
        insertarTexto("<i class='fa-solid fa-house'></i>");
        break;
      case "heart":
        insertarTexto("<i class='fa-solid fa-heart'></i>");
        break;
      case "facebook":
        insertarTexto("<i class='fa-brands fa-facebook'></i>");
        break;
      case "beer":
        insertarTexto("<i class='fa-solid fa-beer-mug-empty'></i>");
        break;
    }
  });
});


// Agregamos un evento click al botón BotonSend
BotonSend.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  pasar_texto();
});

// Función para pasar el texto de miDiv a DivGeneral
function pasar_texto(){
  let mensaje=miDiv.innerHTML
  // Agregamos el contenido de miDiv a DivGeneral
  DivGeneral.innerHTML += "</br>" + miDiv.innerHTML;
  // Limpiamos el contenido de miDiv
  miDiv.textContent = "Ingresa tu texto aquí";
  
  envia_por_ajax(mensaje);
}


function envia_por_ajax(message) {
  //ajax
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating XML object
  xhr.open("POST", "../controllers/insert-chat.php", true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        inputField.value = "";
        scrollToBottom();
      }
    }
  };

  // aqui cambie la info para que tome tus datos y te envie la informacion.
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("outgoing_id", "<?php echo $_SESSION['unique_id']; ?>");
  formData.append("incoming_id", "<?php echo $user_id; ?>");
  formData.append("message", message);
  xhr.send(formData);
}


// Función para insertar texto en el cursor actual
function insertarTexto(texto) {
  const seleccion = window.getSelection();
  const range = seleccion.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  const nuevoContenido = document.createElement("span");
  nuevoContenido.innerHTML = texto;
  range.insertNode(nuevoContenido);
  range.setStartAfter(nuevoContenido);
  seleccion.removeAllRanges();
  seleccion.addRange(range);
}





// Agregar texto de placeholder cuando el div está vacío
if (!miDiv.textContent.trim().length) {
  miDiv.textContent = "Ingresa tu texto aquí";
}

// Eliminar texto de placeholder cuando se hace foco en el div
miDiv.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  if (miDiv.textContent === "Ingresa tu texto aquí") {
    miDiv.textContent = "";
  }
});

// Agregar texto de placeholder cuando se pierde el foco y el div está vacío
miDiv.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  if (!miDiv.textContent.trim().length) {
    miDiv.textContent = "Ingresa tu texto aquí";
  }
});
```

```css
#miDiv  {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 transparent;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
#DivGeneral  {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 transparent;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  float:left;
}


#divmain{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#divmain div{
  float: left;
}
#miDiv:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-rt/SrQ4UNIaGfDyEXZtNcyWvQeOq0QLygHluFQcSjaGB04IxWhal71tKuzP6K8eYXYB6vJV4pHkXcmFGGQ1/0w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<br><br>
<div id="divmain">
    <div contentEditable="true" id="miDiv"></div>
    <div id="BotonSend" class="btn btn-mini btn-info ">
      <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
    </div>
 </div>
<div id="divmain">
<button class="icon" id="house"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></button>
<button class="icon" id="heart"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button>
<button class="icon" id="facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></button>
<button class="icon" id="beer"><i class="fa-solid fa-beer-mug-empty"></i></button>
</div>
<div contentEditable="false" id="DivGeneral"></div>
```

Comment: Te queda bien claro el título? https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido

Comment: Hola te sugerimos editar tu respuesta, evitando agregar varías respuestas. Recuerda nuevamente [revisar esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido)

Comment: @John solo te pedimos seguir las reglas del sitio por favor, anteriormente fue suspendida tu cuenta por el uso de ChatGPT y vuelves a hacer uso del mismo.

Comment: eso no viene al caso, ademas lo uso y siempre lo usare, pero no copio y pego las respuestas como otros

Comment: @Jorgesys Elimine la respuesta por que se enfocaron el la IA y no en verificar claramente si responde o no la pregunta

Comment: @John ¿desde cuando iniciaste a usar ChatGPT en tus respuestas?

Comment: @John creo que yo fui claro, preguntandote como solucionaba tu codigo, el problema de OP. ni siquiera me enfoque en que usaste una IA para tomarlo. Las respuestas deben ser originales, pero sobre todo, completas para que se entiendan. Esta respuesta es peor que la otra. En la otro, por lo menos, explicabas la idea del codigo, aqui ni siquiera. Por favor, aunque copies el codigo, tomate el trabajo de explicarlo correctamente (no con los comentarios de CGPT) y de explicar el problema y la solucion. Asi como esta, esta respuesta es solo codigo.

Comment: @Jorgesys no dije espesifiicamente que uso esa IA para las respuestas, solo que uso una IA para la solución a los problemas, el 90% del tiempo uno debe usar la experiencia para llegar a una solución concreta la IA solo ayuda a escribir mas rapido, y si lo preguntas uso mi propia IA gracias a openIA y colab de google y a mis mas de 20 años programando.

Comment: @gbianchi por si no te diste cuenta la respuesta esta clara, ya savia yo que poner chatGPT iba a iniciar un debate jajajaja, pero tranquilo. ademas no es la única cuenta que tengo en stackoverflow.

Comment: Sinceramente con 20 años de experiencia, no considero que se necesite ayuda de ChatGPT para solucionar problemas, deberías saber que en muchas ocasiones las respuestas que proporciona ChatGPT no dan solucionan un problema.

Comment: @Jorgesys CGPT no da respuestas absolutas, pero ayuda, por ejemplo si necesitas hacer un array o un metodo que reciba algo y responda algo no es necesario escribirlo de 0, tal cual usamos los frameworks, para distintos lenguajes, si necesito usar laravel para crear un sistema empresarial, no se me debe considerar como falta ya que es una herramineta, claro que lo puedo hacer solo con php pero ahorra tiempo, y asi con la mayoria de lenguajes como c#, phyton o Javascript, no considero que usar express para nodejs se considere falta, y un gran etc.

Comment: @Jorgesys ademas, uso IA desde que se inicio el hambito de las redes neuronales por allá del 2.005-2.007 cuando en las universidades de hablaba de una neuronadigital, si en esos tiempos mucho antes que se creara esta plataforma.